# Can't able to understand layout inflater?What it does? and why we use it?

Tags: android, layout-inflater

**I can't able to understand the logic of layout inflater**
What is use the of layout inflater in adapetr class.

```
public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {


    public WordAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Word> words) {
        // Here, we initialize the ArrayAdapter's internal storage for the context and the list.
        // the second argument is used when the ArrayAdapter is populating a single TextView.
        // Because this is a custom adapter for two TextViews and an ImageView, the adapter is not
        // going to use this second argument, so it can be any value. Here, we used 0.
        super(context, 0, words);

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }
```

Comment: Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51729036/what-is-a-layoutinflater-and-how-do-i-use-it-properly/51729037#51729037) one helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go through the [Android Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html).

LayoutInflater (which coverts an XML layout file into corresponding ViewGroups and Widgets) and the way it inflates Views inside Fragment’s onCreateView() method.

LayoutInflater is a class used to instantiate layout XML file into its corresponding view objects which can be used in java programs.